# Is it possible to post a comment to an existing Event using php-sdk?

Tags: events, facebook-php-sdk

I'm able to create and delete events, but haven't found where to post follow-up comments to events.

So, is it even possible to post a comment to an existing event, created by my application, using php-sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you meant "make a post on a event wall" because you can not comment events in Facebook. You can use the PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)) to make any call on the graph API, including posting on an event wall.

You need for that the access token of your application ([see how to get it in the Facebook reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-login)) and the ID of the event (`EVENT_ID`). And then :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(
  'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
  'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
);

$facebook->setAccessToken(YOUR_APP_TOKEN);

$args['message'] = "Hello world !";
$facebook->api('/EVENT_ID/feed', $args);
```

[More on publishing post in the Facebook graph API Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post).

Hope that helps !